# nested sql query with count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an assignment and after hours of pondering and fighting off my illness at the same time, I gave up on a task which I guess is impossible:

I am to print out only the names of cd's which at least have been composed by two composers. all of these informations are stored in 3 tables:
cd (has the cdnr (key) and the name), aufnahme (has the tracks (keys: cdnr and snr (pieces id))) and stueck (has the composers id (knr) and the key snr)

the only soulution i could think of, was counting the tuples of a subquery which distinctly sorts cdnr and knr for each cdnr, but it seems I cannot pass the cdnr from the initial query:

```
select a.cdnr,a.name
from cd a,aufnahme b,stueck c
where a.cdnr=b.cdnr 
and b.snr=c.snr 
and (
    select count(*) from (
        select distinct aufnahme.cdnr,stueck.knr 
        from aufnahme,stueck 
        where aufnahme.snr=stueck.snr
        and aufnahme.cdnr=a.cdnr
    )
)<>1029381 
group by a.cdnr,a.name,c.knr
```

if anyone could help me, I would by very thankfull.

the schema:

```
KOMPONIST (KNR, NAME, VORNAME, GEBOREN, GESTORBEN)
STUECK (SNR, KNR ! KOMPONIST, TITEL, TONART, OPUS)
CD (CDNR, NAME, HERSTELLER, ANZ CDS, GESAMTSPIELZEIT)
AUFNAHME (CDNR ! CD, SNR ! STUECK, ORCHESTER, LEITUNG)
SOLIST ((CDNR, SNR)! AUFNAHME, NAME, INSTRUMENT)
```

EDIT:
After hours (and a good nights sleep) I still have no clue of solving this one. all suggestions - which at first seem a good start - have one problem I cannot think around: they try to group one table. but that could not work, since the table STUECK has nothing to group (snr being the primary key, knr a foreign key). so STUECK and AUFNAHME have to be merged and then the distinct knr's counted and about there I am getting lost.

I know its homework but I still hope someone could help me..

Comment: Since its homework : the hint is to use a count on composers, group by and a having clause.

Comment: @alex - You should post the schema. I (and I guess most of us) have no idea what aufnahme or stueck means.

Comment: @Lieven - you are right, this is more usable. Andrew - "the only solution" was indeed hyperbolic. I tried that the past hours too. I just do not see when I should count the composers. and one last hint : is this difficult or am I missing the obvious? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guess it is impossible??? I can't resist.

```
SELECT cd.name
FROM cd
WHERE cd.CDNR IN
(
  SELECT CDNR
  FROM AUFNAHME 
  GROUP BY CDNR
  HAVING COUNT(SNR) = 2 
)
```

Comment: uhm. that does not work I guess, since every track (each row in STUECK) has only one composer.

Comment: Did you try it?  The key to this *working* is the `GROUP BY SNR` part of the query -- it "combines" rows.

Comment: well, I guess `GROUP BY SNR` would not group, since it is the primary key of `STUECK`, so it is unique. and I suppose `JOIN AUFNAHE A ON cd.CDNR = A.SNR` should mean `A.CDNR`, since these are the corresponding keys. oh and, thank you very, very much for helping! ;)

Comment: but now it only counts `SNR` (the track id), not `KNR` (the composer id)..?

Comment: I'm totally lost in what is what and the relationships.  Maybe you understand the "idea" now?

Comment: @alex: In the subquery, join the `AUFNAHME` table with `STUECK` to get to `KNR`s. Now you will be able to count them. Only you should count *distinct* `KNR` values, so it would be `COUNT(DISTINCT …) = 2`.

Comment: @AndriyM yes, of course! that did it! and now it even makes sense! ;D I would suggest that you put your input into another suggestion, but seeing that Hogan pushed me/the solution into the right direction, I am morally divided. Since ou have more rep than Hogen, are you OK on me checking his (edited) solution as the answering one?

Comment: @alex: Hogan's answer gives the main idea. Mine would be basically same, except it would contain the additional join. I couldn't see a point in there being two almost identical answers in this case. I was thinking about editing this answer, actually, but with my level of English it might take half a day to blend it well. So in the end, it was much easier to add my thoughts as a comment, basing it off of this answer (in the hope that Hogan would later incorporate them in the answer if that were necessary).